# Why does my site domain server address say Index of and list my files?

Tags: domain-name-system, ip-address

I was contacted by one of my client's concerning the DNS issue,they had assigned someone, a task of developing the web portal and deploy it on remote server,however;when they try to check the domain address in the client's browser,the address just displays index of all the directory files,instead of the site,it's self!

This is what the link displays;

[image]

According to my analysis;I think the files are quite open to public and vulnerable.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2530372/how-do-i-disable-directory-browsing and also https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Your site is missing files in the document root. Depending on your server and site, it is most likely a file called index.??????

Comment: @davidgo ,let me try to find out.

Comment: They also have the server set to show a directory listing by default when there's no index file. This is generally considered a bad configuration. None of this has anything to do with DNS.